# Moving object to touch position acting unexpectedly

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Good evening, quick question.

Im developing a top-down 2D platformer game in Unity3D.  Here is a picture of the game.

[image]

I have pretty much everything worked out on a desktop, but when attempting to set up the controls for mobile, I can't seem to get it to work the way it should. All I need is to get the player to move in the direction of wherever the user touches the screen. With the current code im using, the player just rotates in 4 directions, up, down, left and right. He also moves a little, but never goes far from his spawn point.

Please take a look at my revised code:

```
public Camera camera;
public float movespeed = 0;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    movespeed = 2.75F;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        // The screen has been touched so store the touch
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            // If the finger is on the screen, move the object smoothly to the touch position
            Vector3 touchPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, -13)); 
            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - touchPosition, Vector3.back);
            transform.rotation = rot;
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, transform.eulerAngles.z);
            rigidbody2D.angularVelocity = 0;
            //float input = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, touchPosition, Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any ideas on how I can get my player to move to the touched are of the screen? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please define or show an image of what "directions become strange" means.

Comment: Sure. The player follows the mouse cursor until the mouse cursor crosses over to the player's sprite's side. Then the orientation changes. Its like at first if you move your mouse left, the player will rotate left. Then if the mouse ever crosses over to the side of the player's sprite,at that point if you move your mouse left, the player starts turning right. Then The player gets confused and starts spinning out of control. Im thinking the orientation depends on the quadrant of the mouse's position in relation to the player's sprite? Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, you want your player game object to move towards the point on the screen that is being touched. I think it's probably best to describe the behavior of your code so that you can hopefully better understand what might be happening.

From the code posted, I can see one possible issue. Look again at this line:

```
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - touchPosition, Vector3.back);
```

Here, you are asking Unity to calculate the unit quaternion that represents a rotation from the direction of Vector3.forward to the direction from of the player game object from the touch position. This probably isn't what you want. From the description of the problem, you want the game object to rotate to face the point on the screen being touched (rather than the opposite direction). You can either change the order of the subtraction operands or, preferably, use instead the [Transform.LookAt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) method.

After this, you update the transform's rotation:

```
transform.rotation = rot;
```

That's fine, but note that you wouldn't need to do this when using Transform.LookAt.
You then set the transform's rotation again using in this line:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, transform.eulerAngles.z);
```

I'm not entirely sure why you are doing this. If you only want one axis of rotation, you can use, for example:

```
transform.LookAt(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, transform.position.z))
```

This should rotate the player's transform around the z-axis to look in the direction of the point being touched.

Finally, you linearly interpolate the transform's position from its current position to the point being touched:

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, touchPosition, Time.deltaTime);
```

This isn't necessary. Instead, you should just move the player's transform forward. The player should be looking in the direction of the touched screen point. Hence, translating the player forward will move the player towards said screen point:

```
transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

When the player is very close to the touched screen point it will overshoot and immediately rotate to look in the opposite direction. This will occur repeatedly. You should include some distance that specifies when the player is assumed to have reached the target point.

Comment: This works a bit better than before, but it still isn't working the way it should. What happens now is the player rotates to face the point being touched and moves forward. But the sprite is tilted on one of the non-z axes. So the player does move towards the point being touched, but the sprite is twisted on either the x or y axis.Vector3 touchPosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, transform.position.z));
transform.LookAt(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, transform.position.z) * movespeed * Time.deltaTime);

Comment: Wow. Somehow I got it to work... The problem was the camera. It wasn't following the player, so whenever the player moved, his position with respect to the camera changed, therefore affecting his reaction to the touch. Now that the camera is following the player, it's working perfectly. Thanks for the answer anyway. It got me thinking :D